# No puedo reescribir una string en la consola

Tags: c++, string

Estoy escribiendo un programa en c++ en el que el usuario en la consola escribe todas las frases que desea para que luego se cree un archivo con esas frases. Para que el usuario escriba todas las frases que quiera he usado este código.

```
do {
    cout << "Frase: ";
    getline(cin, text);
    file << text << endl;
    cout << "Continue?: ";
    cin >> option;
} while ((option == 'y') || (option == 'Y'));
```

Donde "text" es una variable de tipo string, "option" de tipo char y "file" es el archivo. El problema es que el bucle funciona la primera vez pero después no me deja escribir la string y pasa directamente a "Continue?". El código se ejecuta así en la consola:

Frase: **Hola**

Continue?: **y**

Frase: Continue?:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que cuando lees con `cin` dejas en el stream el `\n`. `getline` lee el stream hasta el siguiente `\n`. Prueba lo siguiente coloca esto de entrada:

```
Frase: Hola
Continue? YHola Mundo
```

Y el archivo queda asi:

```
Hola
Hola Mundo
```

`cin` lee el `Y` y el `Hola Mundo\n` queda en el stream para el `getline`

Entonces lo que puedes hacer es ignorar hasta el siguiente `\n`

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char option;
    string text;
    do {
    cout << "Frase: ";
    getline(cin, text);
    cout << text << endl;
    cout << "Continue?: ";
    cin >> option;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
} while ((option == 'y') || (option == 'Y'));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado, pero podrías explicarme que hace exactamente el "cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');", perdona mi ignorancia pero es que soy nuevo en esto de programar xd.

Comment: El `ignore` va a ignorar tantos caracteres como indique el primer argumento, o hasta que se tope con el carácter de el segundo. Y el `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` te da el numero máximo de caracteres que puede tener el stream. @Gleck